# Annotate graph vertices fails

Tags: graphs-and-networks

According to the docs this should work but for some reason does not:

```
g = CompleteGraph[3];
Annotate[{g, 3}, "a" -> 17];
AnnotationValue[{g, 3}, "a"]
```

It returns `$Failed`, both on desktop and in the cloud. On the other hand, if one uses

```
AnnotationValue[{g, 3}, "a"] = 17
```

the annotation does works. A glitch in paradise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug.

`Annotate` does not modify the graph. Instead, it returns a *new* graph. It is like `Append` and not like `AppendTo`.

```
g = CompleteGraph[3];
g2 = Annotate[{g, 3}, "a" -> 17];
AnnotationValue[{g2, 3}, "a"]
```

Comment: Ah! Each and every (incremental) annotation creates a new graph. Not what 'annotation' typically means and a waste of memory as well, but what can one do.

Comment: @FrancoisVanderseypen "but what can one do" One of two things: (1) your approach with `AnnotationValue[...] = ...` (2) Set multiple properties at the same time. E.g., do not set it vertex by vertex. Set it at once for all vertices. Both will improve performance significantly.

Comment: @FrancoisVanderseypen Also, do check out my IGraph/M package which makes some operations on properties easier, and carefully avoids badly performing constructs (when possible). http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#property-handling-and-transformations